# How to show my .emacs file in finder?

Tags: emacs, macos

I am new to Mac. I installed emacs, but I can't see my .emacs file in the finder. I can open the file from inside emacs, and I saved another copy on my desktop, but it's not showing.

Comment: Do you need to see these files in the Finder or in terminal?

Comment: I just want easy access to my .emacs file so I can make backup copies. And after I made a copy, I would like being able see it so I know where it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These files starting with a dot are meant to be hidden in *nix.

To see them in terminal add the `-a` flag to the `ls` command:

```
ls -a
```

To see them in the Finder you will want to set a hidden preference (this is global change tho, you'll see all your hidden files everywhere):

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```

and then restart the finder:

```
killall Finder
```

To reverse and hide them again:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE && killall Finder
```

[Source](http://osxdaily.com/2009/02/25/show-hidden-files-in-os-x/)

**Update to add:**

Lately I've only been able to get this to work when the string `com.apple.finder` is lower case!  I think this happened starting in 10.9, but not certain.

So you'll want:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE;
```